# how to visual-studio-code auto switch to internal terminal instead of debug console when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know i can set to use internal terminal for debugging. 
However, visual studio code always auto switch to debug console when press F5.

I looked thought the config but seem cannot set jump to internal terminal instead.

Answer (score 7):

in .vscode/launch.json in configurations array in config, ensure that you have these configs:

```
 "console": "integratedTerminal",
 "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
```

Comment: It's a shame I can't vote messages up two times. The Docs should be more clear.